# Проблемы с хлебными крошками. Как исправить?

Tags: jquery, php, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - сделал хлебные крошки на [сайте](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/o-tsentre/условия-проживания/) стандартными средствами Joomla. Хочу убрать надпись "Навигация по сайту". Через CSS делал так:

```
.breadcrumbs_heading div.vt_box>h3>span.vt_heading1>span.vt_heading2{
    display: none;
}
```

И через jQuery пробовал так:

```
$(".breadcrumbs_heading div.vt_box>h3>span.vt_heading1>span.vt_heading2").first().css("display","none");
```

И так, и так надпись исчезает, но перестают работать ссылки (хлебные крошки). В чем может быть проблема? Как исправить этот глюк?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div#vt_feature .vt_box h3 {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Не сработало!

Comment: Извиняюсь, опечатался.

Обновил ответ.